# MYSQL Subquery in Fields list

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have created queries that show me changes happening in our AD.

They check all wanted fields like LastName, FirstName, Location, PhoneNumber etc.
If there is a change in those fields it fills a table called 'changes' inserting the field name of the column that got changed, the Old and New Value and Mail as the UID
i.e.

```
Field | OldValue |  NewValue

LastName | Smith | Peterson
```

The query should update the main table 'users' but only the field that is noted in the table 'changes' with the new value.

Something like

```
  $sql=$MySQLiconn->query("UPDATE users SET (select Field from changes  WHERE id= .$del) = 
(select NewValue from changes  WHERE id=".$del WHERE user.Mail = changes.Mail”;)
```

Is something like this even possible with mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Unfortunatly it is impossible in your way. You have to generate column name before you UPDATE statement.

It would be better and faster in your case.

Comment: so can i do something on the php site?
to set a variable and get the Field Name into that variable and then use the variable in the update query?

Comment: Yes, you can. 

You have to select field from mysql and save into variable. And then, you can use it in your UPDATE query.